# Python: Regex split on space (but keep elements unsplitted in [ ])and add " " in array as a symbol of Newline

Tags: python, regex

Basically imagine if I have a line like this:

```
"Hello world
I am Lucas [help me]
Hi"
```

I'd want the result of `re.split()` to be:

```
['Hello' 'world' '' 'I' 'am' 'Lucas' '[help me] '' 'Hi']
```

As of now I've tried using

```
re.split(r'\s+(?=[^()]*(?:\[|\<|$))', stringToSplit)
```

but I'm uncertain on how to add '' as a newline. I've tried:

```
result = re.split(r'\s|\n+(?=[^()]*(?:\[|\<|$))', input)
```

however this will cause problem for [help me] as it splits it into `'[help' and 'me]'`. Any fixes around this?

Comment: Seems like several questions here... what's the first part you're stuck on? The split?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a *matching* approach to extract all substrings inside square brackets, or non-whitespace chunks, or an empty space before a newline with

```
\[[^[]*]|\([^)]*\)|<[^>]*>|\S+|(?=\n)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4gOYac/4).

**Details**

- `\[[^]]*]` - a `[` followed with any 0+ chars other than `]` and then `]`
- `|` - or
- `\([^)]*\)` - a `(` followed with any chars other than `)` and then `)`
- `|` - or
- `<[^>]*>` - a `<` followed with any 0+ chars other than `>` and then `>`
- `|` - or
- `\S+`  - 1 or more non-whitespace chars
- `|` - or
- `(?=\n)` - an empty string before a `\n`, newline.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9RMKPX):

```
re.findall(r"\[[^[]*]|\([^)]*\)|<[^>]*>|\S+|(?=\n)", s)
# => ['Hello', 'world', '', 'I', 'am', 'Lucas', '[help me]', '(help me 2)', '<help me 3>', '', 'Hi']
```

Comment: What if I want [help me](I'm trapped) to be one element instead of two?

Comment: @LuftWoofe See an example on how to extend the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [**newer regex module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) you could get along with:

```
import regex as re

string = """Hello world
I am Lucas [help me]
Hi"""

rx = re.compile(r'\[[^][]*\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\s+)')

parts = rx.split(string)
print(parts)
# ['Hello', ' ', 'world', '\n', 'I', ' ', 'am', ' ', 'Lucas', ' ', '[help me]', '\n', 'Hi']
```

It matches any unwanted constructions such as `[...]` and lets them fail afterwards. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/7rNEhL/1).